# Wrap text around figure on whole page

Tags: floats, multicol, wrapfigure, wrap

In my document I have a huge data flow graph that is exactly one page high. Since it is not very wide I'd like to have it on the left/right side of one page while having normal text on the other side.

Most intuitive way would be to use `wrapfig`, but this package always places the figure at the very end of the current chapter. This is kind of strange behavious since I can verify by changing the `wrapfigure` environment to a `figure` environment that the figure does fit on one page.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\def\n{3}

\newcommand{\bridgedblock}[1]{
    % args 1: num featuremaps, 2: divide by two, 3: fill color, 4: name prefix
    \node[normalnode] (#1-node1) {\scriptsize label1};
    \begin{scope}[node distance=0.25cm]
        \node[normalnode] (#1-node2) {\scriptsize label2};
    \end{scope}

    \path (#1-node1) edge (#1-node2);
    \path[draw, shorten >=0pt] ($(#1-node1.north) + (0cm, 0.175cm)$) -| ($(#1-node1) + (2cm,-0.5cm)$) |- ($(#1-node2.south) - (0cm, 0.125cm)$);
}

\newcommand{\insertpicture}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.55cm, start chain=going below, shorten >=1pt, ->]
        \tikzstyle{normalnode}=[draw, rectangle, text centered, on chain,
                          minimum height=0.3cm, text width=3cm]
        \tikzstyle{empty}=[text centered, on chain]

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\boundary}{\n - 1}

        \node[empty] (input) {\scriptsize x};
        \node[normalnode] (init-node) {\scriptsize label1}; 

        \foreach \twopow in {32, 16, 8} {

            \bridgedblock{\twopow-1};
            \foreach \name [evaluate=\name as \pred using int(\name - 1)] in {2,...,\boundary} {
                \bridgedblock{\twopow-\name};
                \path (\twopow-\pred-node2) edge (\twopow-\name-node1);
            }
            \bridgedblock{\twopow-last}
            \path (\twopow-\boundary-node2) edge (\twopow-last-node1);
        }

        \node[empty] (noboxnode) {\scriptsize noboxnode};
        \node[normalnode] (lastnode) {\scriptsize lastnode};
        \node[empty] (output) {\scriptsize};

        \path (input) edge (init-node);
        \path (init-node) edge (32-1-node1);
        \path (32-last-node2) edge (16-1-node1);
        \path (16-last-node2) edge (8-1-node1);
        \path (8-last-node2) edge (noboxnode);
        \path (noboxnode) edge (lastnode);
        \path (lastnode) edge (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Section 1}

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \insertpicture
    \caption{A very very long data flow graph.}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\section{Section 2}

\section{Section 3}

\section{Section 4}

\end{document}
```

What I have already tried:

- Using package `floatflt` with `floatingfigure` yields the same behaviour.
- Using `multicol` with environment `multicols` doesn't show the figure at all. Futhermore it is very uncomfortable since you need to decide which text goes next to the figure.

Maybe some of you know another trick.

Comment: Is a double column layout (only for the page containing the chart) an option?

Comment: Yes, it definitely would be an option. Is there another way to achieve this besides using `multicol`? Like I wrote above, `multicol` doesn't work for strange reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapfig wants to start at the start of a paragraph, so it's best to get a start of a paragraph at the top of the page to give yourself a full page height:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\def\n{3}

\newcommand{\bridgedblock}[1]{
    % args 1: num featuremaps, 2: divide by two, 3: fill color, 4: name prefix
    \node[normalnode] (#1-node1) {\scriptsize label1};
    \begin{scope}[node distance=0.25cm]
        \node[normalnode] (#1-node2) {\scriptsize label2};
    \end{scope}

    \path (#1-node1) edge (#1-node2);
    \path[draw, shorten >=0pt] ($(#1-node1.north) + (0cm, 0.175cm)$) -| ($(#1-node1) + (2cm,-0.5cm)$) |- ($(#1-node2.south) - (0cm, 0.125cm)$);
}

\newcommand{\insertpicture}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.55cm, start chain=going below, shorten >=1pt, ->]
        \tikzstyle{normalnode}=[draw, rectangle, text centered, on chain,
                          minimum height=0.3cm, text width=3cm]
        \tikzstyle{empty}=[text centered, on chain]

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\boundary}{\n - 1}

        \node[empty] (input) {\scriptsize x};
        \node[normalnode] (init-node) {\scriptsize label1}; 

        \foreach \twopow in {32, 16, 8} {

            \bridgedblock{\twopow-1};
            \foreach \name [evaluate=\name as \pred using int(\name - 1)] in {2,...,\boundary} {
                \bridgedblock{\twopow-\name};
                \path (\twopow-\pred-node2) edge (\twopow-\name-node1);
            }
            \bridgedblock{\twopow-last}
            \path (\twopow-\boundary-node2) edge (\twopow-last-node1);
        }

        \node[empty] (noboxnode) {\scriptsize noboxnode};
        \node[normalnode] (lastnode) {\scriptsize lastnode};
        \node[empty] (output) {\scriptsize};

        \path (input) edge (init-node);
        \path (init-node) edge (32-1-node1);
        \path (32-last-node2) edge (16-1-node1);
        \path (16-last-node2) edge (8-1-node1);
        \path (8-last-node2) edge (noboxnode);
        \path (noboxnode) edge (lastnode);
        \path (lastnode) edge (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Section 1}

\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1-3]


\begin{wrapfigure}[44]{o}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \insertpicture
    \caption{A very very long data flow graph.}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[4-20]

\section{Section 2}

\section{Section 3}

\section{Section 4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer although I also used @Rmano's trick to scale down the graphics.
+1 for the nice trick with the [44] parameter. I didn't know about that specifying the number of lines to be wrapped.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest putting your figure in the margin. Actually there doesn't remain enough height on the first page of the chapter to insert it with a simple `\InsertBoxR` without perturbating the line lengths of the following pages, unless you scale the figure by a  small factor. This seems to be due to the insertion of a section title.

Thus I propose this code:

```
\input{insbox.tex}
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\def\n{3}

\newcommand{\bridgedblock}[1]{
    % args 1: num featuremaps, 2: divide by two, 3: fill color, 4: name prefix
    \node[normalnode] (#1-node1) {\scriptsize label1};
    \begin{scope}[node distance=0.25cm]
        \node[normalnode] (#1-node2) {\scriptsize label2};
    \end{scope}

    \path (#1-node1) edge (#1-node2);
    \path[draw, shorten >=0pt] ($(#1-node1.north) + (0cm, 0.175cm)$) -| ($(#1-node1) + (2cm,-0.5cm)$) |- ($(#1-node2.south) - (0cm, 0.125cm)$);
}

\newcommand{\insertpicture}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.55cm, start chain=going below, shorten >=1pt, ->]
        \tikzstyle{normalnode}=[draw, rectangle, text centered, on chain,
                          minimum height=0.3cm, text width=3cm]
        \tikzstyle{empty}=[text centered, on chain]

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\boundary}{\n - 1}

        \node[empty] (input) {\scriptsize x};
        \node[normalnode] (init-node) {\scriptsize label1};

        \foreach \twopow in {32, 16, 8} {

            \bridgedblock{\twopow-1};
            \foreach \name [evaluate=\name as \pred using int(\name - 1)] in {2,...,\boundary} {
                \bridgedblock{\twopow-\name};
                \path (\twopow-\pred-node2) edge (\twopow-\name-node1);
            }
            \bridgedblock{\twopow-last}
            \path (\twopow-\boundary-node2) edge (\twopow-last-node1);
        }

        \node[empty] (noboxnode) {\scriptsize noboxnode};
        \node[normalnode] (lastnode) {\scriptsize lastnode};
        \node[empty] (output) {\scriptsize};

        \path (input) edge (init-node);
        \path (init-node) edge (32-1-node1);
        \path (32-last-node2) edge (16-1-node1);
        \path (16-last-node2) edge (8-1-node1);
        \path (8-last-node2) edge (noboxnode);
        \path (noboxnode) edge (lastnode);
        \path (lastnode) edge (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{caption, marginnote, adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\marginnote{%
\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\centering\adjustbox{width=\marginparwidth}{\insertpicture}
\captionsetup{format=plain, font =footnotesize}\captionof{figure}{A very very long data flow graph.}%
 }}%
\lipsum[1]
{\section{Section 1}}%

\lipsum

\section{Section 2}

\section{Section 3}

\section{Section 4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the seemingly less "hacky" solutions here made it work for me I stuck to them. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that the figures (with all the spaces for captions, etc.)  *does* fit in a raw page, but not in the text height allocated space. I checked by adding `\vspace*{-4cm}` before the `centering` in the `wrapfigure`:

```
 \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.4\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-4cm}
    \centering
    \insertpicture
    \caption{A very very long data flow graph.}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

...and the result page is:

[image: Output with negative vspace]

and at a glance it seems that the graph will not fit (consider that it should fit *below* the chapter heading...). So I changed the graph definition (at the start) as:

```
\newcommand{\insertpicture}[1][1.0]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,transform shape, node distance=0.55cm, start chain=going below, shorten >=1pt, ->]
...
```

and now I have, with:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \insertpicture[0.8]
    \caption{A very very long data flow graph.}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

this result:

[image: result scaling down]

which I think it is more or less what you looked for.

Comment: Your answer in combination with @David Carlisle's made it work. Thanks!